# Full Screen with Watir Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, watir

I'd like to put my browser in full-screen mode (not just maximize the window), but I'm struggling to find a way to do so in the watir documentation.  I thought of maybe sending the f11 key to the browser instance directly, but it seems that isn't possible.

Any ideas on a workaround?

Please note, I'm not looking to do browser.window.maximize, I'm looking for the way it looks when you hit F11 when the browser is active.

Comment: What programming language is this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is part of the new W3C webdriver specification, but hasn't been implemented in any browser driver yet. As of right now you can't automate in full screen.